# How to improve read performance on a partitioned (using inheritance) PostgreSQL table over the same version of clustered table with ~50M rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, database-partitioning

I have the following tables for storing time series metric data in my PostgreSQL 12 instance -

```
 CREATE TABLE metric_values
(
    event_id bigint NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    value numeric(20,4) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE metric_values_old
(
    event_id bigint NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    value numeric(20,4) NOT NULL
)
```

The two tables are identical with index on event_id and timestamp columns. The difference is metric_values_old is having ~50M rows and is clustered based on the above index, while metric_values is partitioned by inheritance, with individual indexes and clustering created on each child.

Each partition is supposed to hold data for 1 year, derived from the timestamp column.

Here is the definition of one the child tables -

```
CREATE TABLE metric_values_2021
(
    -- Inherited from table metric_values: event_id bigint NOT NULL,
    -- Inherited from table metric_values: "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    -- Inherited from table metric_values: value numeric(20,4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT metric_values_2021_event_id_timestamp_key UNIQUE (event_id, "timestamp"),
    CONSTRAINT metric_values_2021_timestamp_check CHECK (date_part('year'::text, "timestamp") = 2021)
)
    INHERITS (metric_values)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX metric_values_2021_idx
    ON metric_values_2021 USING btree
    (event_id ASC NULLS LAST, "timestamp" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE metric_values_2021
    CLUSTER ON metric_values_2021_idx;
```

But while comparing the query performance for both these tables, the partitioned table is performing worse than the clustered table. I was expecting the performance to be better since the query has conditions on timestamp, and would be able to retrieve from a particular child. I would prefer to go with partitioning since it will be easier to maintain going forward and each child table will have a fixed size unlike the clustered table with 50M rows and growing.

Below are the queries I tried on both tables -

```
select event_id, timestamp, value from metric_values
WHERE timestamp between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'

select event_id, timestamp, value from metric_values_old
WHERE timestamp between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'
```

Following are the explain plans -

1. Clustered table with no partitioning

   [image]
2. Partitioned Table

   [image]

It seems for the partitioned table this is scanning all partitions hence the increased cost. Any suggestions on improving this performance will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Followed the suggestion from @a_horse_with_no_name and was able to resolve the issue for the query -

```
select event_id, timestamp, value from metric_values
WHERE timestamp between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'
```

[image]

Although the performance is way better, PostgreSQL still seems to scan all partitions. If anybody is aware of the reason or if there is a way to avoid this, do let me know. All your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using inheritance based partitioning any more. Declarative partitioning is much more efficient and it's much better integrated into the optimizer and therefor partitioning pruning works a lot better. You should use at least Postgres 12 for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the tip. Let me try that. One of the drawbacks is I am unable to automate creation of partitions and routing inserts into the appropriate partition using a row trigger, which works with inheritance. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You don't need a trigger with declarative partitioning. Postgres will automatically insert the row into the correct partition: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f99f23409e416be31f5bad493083196b

Comment: "Rows removed by filter", there is no useful index at all. And the WHERE condition doesn't match the constraint conditions either so it has to read everything to find the data you actually need.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! It worked like a charm. I will update the solution here

Comment: @FrankHeikens There was a multi-column index. I dropped event_id from indexing and the performance was much better

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe I misinterpreted the requirement for automating partition creation. I wanted a solution where partition can be created on the fly during inserts when none exists, but couldn't find a solution without trigger. I have manually created partitions for now, might automate that using a scheduled script later on.

Comment: Why pay the cost of checking if a partition exists over and over again for each and every row you insert, when you can easily pre-create partitions in advance? Especially when partitioning by year, you can just create those for the next 10 years or so. Or have a cron job that runs in December to create the partition for next year.

Comment: The remaining performance issues are related to your WHERE and CONSTRAINT conditions. The constraint says "date_part('year'::text, "timestamp") = 2021" while your WHERE condition doesn't mention these conditions at all. I would change the constraint and use a timestamp between start and end of the year.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I changed the where clause as you suggested and its looking into that specific partition now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by changing from inheritance to declarative approach. Please refer to the solution suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f99f23409e416be31f5bad493083196b